# System to format at least 10 laptop SATA drives

Tags: hard-disk, server, data-storage, sata

Hi I'm looking for a system/rack or something similar which will be capable of formatting 10 SATA drives.

It can be more but no less than 10 drives.

I was thinking of some kind of server rack with the soul purpose of formatting the drives. Is this a good idea? I'm open to an suggestions as long as they involve formatting multiple drives from a single system/rack.
I'd like to keep costs down as well.

Also is there commercial software that supports the format of multiple drives?

[image]

Comment: What size drives?  2.5-inch, 3.5-inch, 1.8-inch, something else entirely?

Comment: What about something like this?: https://www.kanguru.com/mobile/m.duplicators-kanguruclone-hard-drive-duplicator-11hd-tower.html

Comment: This is a bunch of similar stuff from the same site: https://www.kanguru.com/mobile/m.duplicators-hard-drive-solid-state-drive.html

Comment: @Mark The drives are exactly like in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

You're honestly better off just formatting each hard drive individually. It would probably take less time to format them one by one than to search around for a good deal on a 10x hard drive supporting server rack. It probably wouldn't be worth the money at all to buy a new rack and barely worth it to buy a second hand server for the sole purpose of formatting hard drives.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah I'm doing this at work so I can bring up a proposition to the boss in order to get the appropriate finances. We have been having a lot of problems with the recording on these drives so I wanted to find the most efficient way to format in bulk.